# Enlarge image on grid when click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a thumbnail grid and what I want to do is to enlarge (just a little bit) an image (over the others that are next, top and bottom) without making the grid messy.

I have been trying with different alternatives, first to accomplish the action of showing the image, then to accomplish the dynamics.

```css
#thumbnail-grid {
   background-color: #1F1F1F; 
   height: 450px;
}

#thumbs {
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  
  position: relative;
}

img {
   float: left;
   margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
   z-index: 10;
}

.ontop {
  z-index: 200;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="thumbnail-grid">
  <div id="thumbs">
    <img class="thumbnail" src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
    <img class="thumbnail ontop" src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
    <img class="thumbnail" src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
    <img class="thumbnail" src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
    <img class="thumbnail" src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
    <img class="thumbnail" src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
    <img class="thumbnail ontop" src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
    <img class="thumbnail" src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
  </div>
</div>
```

the problem is that in my real grid when I try to do this to the last image, it appears on the right side, out of the grid and in the first row.

Can anyone please give a tip? an a css book recommendation please

Comment: There are a couple of options, but the easiest (assuming you have modern browser requirements) would be `transform: scale()`.

Comment: @BenjaminSolum if I use transform scale, the enlarged image moves the other next to it

Comment: Position relative the container and position absolute the image. That will remove the image from the flow so it doesn't run against other elements while maintaining its position.

Comment: @BenjaminSolum thanks, but I think that is already in my code..and still have the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS transform for that:

```
.ontop {
    transform: scale(1.1); // 1.1 means "scale to 110% of original size"
}
```

If you need wider browser support, add vendor-prefixed properties.

Keep in mind, that your image quality can get a little bit blurred using this approach.

Comment: Using scale is actually making an image big, but it moves the others next to it

Comment: Actually it shouldn't... By using transform scale, only the visual part of a block gets enlarged, the "rendering block part", which affects the rest of the layout, stays untouched. That's why animating/transitioning using transform is so much more performant than using other properties (like e.g. margin).